# Linq where clause with nullable parameters

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to do a linq query which might have nullable params.

This is my linq call

```
listOfControlsVM = db.Controls.Where((status == null || s.Status.Description == status) && (impact == null || s.Impact == impact)).ToList();
```

Now either status or impact can be nullable params (I have two more but I removed them from the example). With the approach I have the query doesn't return the correct set of results.

I want to know if there is other better approach to work with nullable params in linq. For example if status or impact have value include them in the conditions, otherwise skip them.

Comment: You can find many similar questions/solutions on SO. Chained `Where` is my favorite approach. But the approach you are using is the second viable choice, so what really doesn't work - can you give an example of "query doesn't return the correct set of results"?

Comment: Thx for your reply @IvonStoev. I know the amount of results which should be returned from the db and when I compare them with what I have returned from the linq query they don't match. What I'm trying to achieve is completely exclude the parameter from the where clause if the value is null. Thx

Comment: Then try [chaining where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bentity-framework%5D+or+%5Bentity-framework-6%5D+chained+where) approach. e.g. `var query = db.Controls.AsQueryable(); if (status != null) query = query.Where(s => s.Status.Description == status); if (impact != null) query = query.Where(s => s.Impact == impact);` etc. I'm pretty sure the question is duplicate, that's why not posting answer.

Comment: What does the SQL generated look like?

Answer (score 2):

There is a `HasValue` to check null value on `nullable` variable instead of null.

```
 listOfControlsVM = db.Controls.Where((!status.HasValue || s.Status.Description == status) && (!impact.HasValue || s.Impact == impact)).ToList();
```

I hope this will help you out :)